# Error while replaying SignalR interactions in Fiddler

Tags: signalr, fiddler

I'm trying to replicate a .NET client's interaction with a SignalR hub. I captured the interactions of the client using Fiddler. The `negotiate` call goes through fine. But when I try to replay the `connect` call i.e.

```
/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=W%2BHgJKpBzSOoa3AG4uID8DtrJZeJs5a5Tvwk%2BXqwJl6hb0eJN9qtG5hEfOS8IYPiZSrKyEZRWbA9Go7cN5So36z4%2BI%2F0QX1VSZn0lgy6GCFWvKQwAWHwGMgnpmhVRuR%2B&connectionData=[%7B%22Name%22:%22ABCD%22%7D]
```

The response is an HTTP 400 and the error text is

```
2c
The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.
0
```

The connectionToken is not stale for sure. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the purpose of this excersise?

Comment: Please share the *complete* connection request, as well as details of how specifically you attempted to replay it.